# HTACCESS REQUEST_URI without the filename

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(images)
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(txt|rtf|docx?|odt|pdf|bmp|gif|jpe?g|png|tiff?)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/~abc123/uploader/process.php [nc]
```

Is there any way of not having to quote `~abc123/uploader` but to modify my regular expression so that the request_uri without the filename is dynamically passed through?

I've tried looking at removing the filename from the request_uri and also changing my regular expression but to no avail.

What I'm trying to do is to make sure certain file types are processed by a PHP script and cannot be accessed directly.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two clues that might help you:

First, you can use those keywords into your regular expression (I let you google for more information) : `%{SCRIPT_FILENAME}` and `%{REQUEST_URI}`

Second, here's an example of how to use it:

```
 # (1) if domain name is static:
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.s\.(.*) [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.static\.(.*) [NC]
 # (2) and it's not the JavaScript directory:
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/(.*)$
 # (3) *always* add /templates/ (if not there):
 RewriteRule /(templates/)*(.*) /templates/$2 [L]
```

And a few people know that you can even change the whole destination filename this way (note: the `STATIC` and `PATH_LOCAL` variable is an environment variable that I've calculated a few steps before):

```
# If static...
RewriteCond %{ENV:STATIC} 1
# ...first test to see if the file exists in the language path:
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:PATH_LOCAL}/%{ENV:EXT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -f  
# It exists => rewrite filename then end:
RewriteRule  ^(.+) %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{ENV:PATH_LOCAL}/%{ENV:EXT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the clues but I'm still at a loss.
I don't want to have to quote and replace a string for another as in your templates example where in your rule you are quoting the string 'templates'.
I simply want to strip out the request_filename and attach it to 'process.php' for the final part of my rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}        ^(?!images)(.*)/[-\w\.]*$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)\.(txt|rtf|docx?|odt|pdf|bmp|gif|jpe?g|png|tiff?)$   http://%{SERVER_NAME}/%1/process.php [NC,L]
```

will do what you ask.  The (?!...) is a negative lookahead i.e don't include images.  The [-\w.]*$ bit will match normal file names.  What I don't understand is that a `http://%{SERVER_NAME}/...` redirect without the [R] is just a normal internal rewrite why you don't just do

```
RewriteRule  ^(?!images)(.*)/[-\w]*\.(?:txt|rtf|docx?|odt|pdf|bmp|gif|jpe?g|png|tiff?)$  $1/process.php [NC,L]
```

Without any conds or

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} !^images
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI} (txt|rtf|docx?|odt|pdf|bmp|gif|jpe?g|png|tiff?)$
RewriteRule  ^(.*)/.*       $1/process.php [NC,L]
```

if you want to keep it easier to understand.